# Visual Studio 2015 does not work with Apache Cordova 8.1

Tags: android, java-7, visual-studio-cordova

I'm stuck with trying to make Apache Cordova work in Visual studio 2015 Enterprise update 2. It is not seeing android and java. It refused to install Android setup 19 and 21.
I instead android studio and from there, installed API level 19 and 21, but visual studio is still not seeing it.
After creating a new project, when I click on debug, I get this error message:
[debugging error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4WB5.png)

I have tried so many other options, from google. like Tools->Options->Project and Solutions, I cannot find JavaScript option to set JDK and SDK paths.
Pls any help will really be appreciated. I'm a newbie to mobile app development.
Thanks in advance

Sorry for my late reply. I decided to install visual studio 2013 Professional, and update 5 too (although the update stopped midway due to poor internet connection) to see if it will help, somehow it did. I'm now able to set the paths for android.
When I tried running hello world now, the error message is " Failed to fetch platform android" - getaddrinfo ENOENT - File MDAVSCLI.
I'm really tired of all this!! Pls help.

Comment: The error message is not readable at all from that image. Please copy (or **type** if you have to) the contents of that error message verbatim into your question, in plain text.

Comment: Is this just a debug problem, or do you get error messages when you build? If so add the relevant part of the build log to your question.

Comment: check the section "To override the variables" https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/configure-vs-tools-apache-cordova/#ThirdParty to find the path settings. And as a general check, I will suggest you go to programs and features to ensure the required components or dependencies are checked and installed by following the instructions mentioned in section "Add the Apache Cordova feature after you install Visual Studio" and "The third-party components that Visual Studio installs for you" in http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/install-vs-tools-apache-cordova/

Answer (score 0):

Wow it is working now. I tried installing npm and bower globally from cmd. Then I cleared Cordova cache from Tools->Options. And with my internet connected, I ran the Hello world again. It went through this time.